# Json array in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

Hi I have a problem with json array in postgresql.
I have this query

```
select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t)))
from (
  select id, ids, liv, tip, ide, idf nome, ico, rgb,
    (
      select array_to_json(array_agg(d))
      from (
        select a_attributi_id
        from m_attributi_oggetti
        where m_oggetti_id = sgoc.moggid
      ) d
    ) as attrs
  from sinfo_get_oggetti_catalogo() sgoc
  ) t
```

with data output like this

```
[{"id":"1026.148","ids":2,"liv":148,"tip":1,"ide":0,"nome":126,"ico":"flagman.png","rgb":"255,127,0",**"attrs":[{"a_attributi_id":21},{"a_attributi_id":45}]**}]
```

but I want this json :

```
[{"id":"1026.148","ids":2,"liv":148,"tip":1,"ide":0,"nome":126,"ico":"flagman.png","rgb":"255,127,0",**"attrs":[21,45]**}]
```

Is this possible through the json function in postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

```
select regexp_replace(array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t)))
from (
  select id, ids, liv, tip, ide, idf nome, ico, rgb,
    (
      select array_to_json(array_agg(d))
      from (
        select a_attributi_id
        from m_attributi_oggetti
        where m_oggetti_id = sgoc.moggid
      ) d
    ) as attrs
  from sinfo_get_oggetti_catalogo() sgoc
  ) t), '{.*:([^}'+)','\1');
```

Should work for you... If not, do leave a comment and I'll help further.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you use `array_to_json(array_agg(d))`: that will aggregate the whole `d` row (no matter it contains only one column) into the array. If you want to aggregate the atomic value, you should use the exact column, like `array_to_json(array_agg(a_attributi_id))`.

You can also drop some unnecessary conversion to `json`, you can convert all your values at the *end*.

```
select array_to_json(array_agg(t))
from (
  select id, ids, liv, tip, ide, idf nome, ico, rgb,
    ( select array_agg(a_attributi_id)
      from m_attributi_oggetti
      where m_oggetti_id = sgoc.moggid
    ) as attrs
  from sinfo_get_oggetti_catalogo() sgoc
) t
```